# AngularJS - Comparing resources and objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, some method calls return **Objects**, and some return **Resources**, which make them difficult to compare.  I have a user model and a permission model.  The user model is defined:

```js
myApp.service('User', function($resource) {
  var User = $resource('users/:userId.json');
  return User;
});
```

And the permission model is defined:

```js
myApp.service('Permission', function($resource) {
  var Permission = $resource('permissions');
  return Permission;
});
```

When I retrieve a user, the json returned has the user's permissions:

```js
{"id":1,"username":"Admin","group_id":"1","permissions":[{"id":1,"name":"Create Users"},"id":2,"name":"Delete Users"}]}
```

This means when I retrieve a user, I can access his/her permissions with .permissions  For example

```js
User.get({userId: 1}).permissions
```

I want to compare this with the list of all permissions, and get a list of the permissions that the user does not already have:

```js
$scope.user = User.get({userId: 1});
Permission.query().$promise.then(function(all){
  $scope.user.$promise.then(function(u){
    $scope.unselected_permissions = _.difference(all, u.permissions);
  });
});
```

The problem is, `all` is an array of **Resources**, and `u.permissions` is an array of **Objects**.  Is there a simple way to get `u.permissions` to return a list of resources?  Is there something simpler I can do instead of waiting for the promises to resolve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating my own differences method that compares on id:

```
Permission.query().$promise.then(function(all){
  $scope.user.$promise.then(function(u){
    $scope.unselected_permissions = all.filter(function(p){
      return !u.permissions.some(function(q){return p.id == q.id;});
    });
  });
});
```